# Programmatically generated function, how to define doc?

Tags: julia

I want to define some functions as described in the [official doc](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Code-Generation) but with some documentation.

Minimal reproducible example :

```
julia> cases = ( :A => 1, :B => 2 )
(:A => 1, :B => 2)

julia> for (name,value) in cases
           func_name = Symbol("foo_"*string(name))
           eval(quote
                    $func_name() = $value
                end)
       end

julia> foo_A()
1

julia> foo_B()
2
```

**My problem** is that I want to also define some associated doc :

```
help?> foo_A
search: foo_A foo_B unsafe_pointer_to_objref

  No documentation found.

  foo_A is a Function.

  # 1 method for generic function "foo_A":
  [1] foo_A() in Main at REPL[2]:4
```

I can do :

```
for (name,value) in cases
    func_name = Symbol("foo_"*string(name))
    eval(quote
             " The function doc is here "
             $func_name() = $value
         end)
end
```

in that case :

```
help?> foo_A()
  The function doc is here
```

But what I really need is some kind of **substitution** :

```
julia> for (name,value) in cases
           func_name = Symbol("foo_"*string(name))
           eval(quote
                    " The function $name returns $value"
                    $func_name() = $value
                end)
       end
ERROR: UndefVarError: name not defined
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `@doc` macro:

```
for (name,value) in cases
    func_name = Symbol("foo_"*string(name))
    docstr = " The function $name returns $value"
    eval(quote
        @doc $docstr $func_name() = $value
    end)
end
```

Now yo can do as expected:

```
julia> foo_A(), foo_B()
(1, 2)

help?> foo_A
search: foo_A foo_B unsafe_pointer_to_objref

  The function A returns 1

help?> foo_B
search: foo_B unsafe_pointer_to_objref foo_A

  The function B returns 2
```